# Existe registro en un dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio

Supongamos que tengo este dataframe en R

```
data <- c("a", "c", "d", "e", "F")
llave <- c("1a","2b", "3c", "4c", "5c")
data <- cbind(data,llave)
data <- data.frame(data)
```

lo que busco que una forma en la que me regrese un valor si mi búsqueda no existe, por ejemplo: si busco:

```
data[data$llave == "1a",]
```

me regresa

```
 data llave
1    a    1a
```

pero si busco

```
data[data$llave == "5a",]
```

este registro no existe, me gustaría tener algo como una especie de if

```
if(data[data$llave == "5a",] == 0){
#accion
}else{
#accion
}
```

al hacer esto; me marca "argumento tiene longitud cero" debido a que el registro que busco efectivamente no existe. Tengo que hacer esta validación debido de un dataframe a que contiene un conjunto de llaves, en otros dataframe b pero puede que una de las llaves de a no existe en uno de los dataframe de b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías validar el número de filas del data.frame resultante del subconjunto y hacer una cosa si >0 y otra si =0 (que sería el caso en el que no encuentra el registro).

Va una función que hace eso,internamente usa `subset()` en lugar de `[` por simpleza del código. Es una solución ad hoc y no me parece que sea la mejor, pero está en línea con tu pregunta:

```
data <- data.frame(data = c("a", "c", "d", "e", "F"),
                   llave = ("1a","2b", "3c", "4c", "5c"), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


misubset <- function(x, registro) {
  out <- subset(x, llave == registro)
  if (nrow(out) == 0) {
    print("el registro no existe")  #Podrías retornar un NULL u otra cosa que te sirva
  } else {
    return(out)}
}
```

El nombre `llave` está mencionado explícitamente en el código, cuidado.

## Test

```
misubset(data, "5a")
misubset(data, "1a")
```